# Reading a file that is being written to - Locking it?

Tags: java, io

There is a file - stored on an external server which is updated very frequently by a vendor. My application polls this file every minute getting the values out. All I am doing is reading the file.

I am worried that by doing this I could inadvertently lock the file so it cant be written too by the vendor. Is this a possibility?

Kind regards

Comment: How do you read the file? "External server" means network? NFS? HTTP?

Comment: Reading the file via the use of xpath. The file is accessed via network

Comment: Does the writer only append data, or does it also update? In the second case I would try to find a different solution.

Comment: Do you know how the writer would react in case of a readlock?

Comment: it updates the file - with new values. its a smallish xml file. i have no idea how it would react in case of a readlock

Comment: Unfortunately this is OS specific. Windows programs are often particularly inconsistent in their behaviour in this regard. (UNIX usually avoids the issue entirely) IMHO, If your vendors application isn't designed to support this, they should provide a means which is.

Comment: HTTP protocol doesn't provide any method to lock a file. I think you should download a file and process it locally (I guess you already do that in memory). It's reasonable assumption that if a file would be modified while you download it you will get a previous version of a file. If server doesn't guarantee that you could check it checksum if it is provided and eventually redownload it.

Comment: I agree with Peter : this is OS-specific. If your lucky enough that your file is actually stored on a Unix this should not be an issue. If your file is stored on Windows, you are in trouble indeed. One solution if you can launch commands on the server is to launch a "COPY yourfile yourfile.tmp" on the server (which is fast and should be non disruptive for your vendor) and then read from the copy.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Eric's answer - you could check the Last Modified Property of the temp file and only merge it with your 'working' file when it changes - that should protect you from read/write conflicts and only merge files just after the vendor has written to the temp. Though this is messy and mrab's comment is valid, a better solution should be found.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem several times, and as Peter Lawrey says there isn't any portable way to do this, and if your environment is Unix this should not be an issue at all as these concurrent access conditions are properly managed by the operating systems. However windows do not handle this at all (yes, that's the consequence of using an amateur OS for production work, lol).

Now that's said, there is a way to solve this if your vendor is flexible enough. They could write to a temp file and when finished move the temp file to the final destination. By doing this you avoid any concurrent access to the file between you and the vendor.

Another way is to precisely (difficult?) know the timing of your vendors update and avoid reading the file during some time frames. For instance if your vendor update the file every hour, avoid reading from five-to-the-hour to five-past-the-hour.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Windows Shadow Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) service for volumes. This would allow to read the backup copy.

If the third party software is in java too, and uses a Logger, that should be tweakable: every minute writing to the next from 10 files or so.

I would try to relentlessly read the file (when modified since last read), till something goes wrong. Maybe you can make a test run with hundreds of reads in the weekend or at midnight, when no harm is done.

***My answer:***
Maybe you need a local watch program, [a watch service for a directoryr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html), that waits till the file is modified, and then makes a fast cooy; after that allowing the copy to be transmitted.